# Quasi-local mass as a measure of the gravitational energy?

Tags: general-relativity

I'm self-studying the mathematical aspects of quasi-local mass, or quasi-local energy, and a fundamental question has been lingering in my mind for a long time: why does quasi-local mass provide us with a measure of the gravitational energy? In general relativity, gravitation is seen as a consequence of the curved spacetime instead of a force, which we would encounter in classical mechanics. If so, how can we talk about its energy without considering it as a force field? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give us a bit more context? What kind of quasi-local mass are you looking at.

Comment: @TimRias Thank you. I'm studying Hawking mass: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_energy